# Xquery calculate average on attribute

Tags: attributes, xquery, average

I have an XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="class3.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<school>
<student><name>Jack T</name>
<course title="INF8430" note="78" />
<course title="INF1030" note="69" />
<course title="INF1230" note="85" /></student>
<student><name>Marty L</name>
<course title="INF8430" note="95" />
<course title="INF1030" note="82" />
<course title="INF1230" note="77" /></student>
<student><name>Ben L</name>
<course title="INF9430" note="59" />
<course title="INF1030" note="78" />
<course title="INF1230" note="79" /></student>
</school>
```

In my XQuery I use this :

```
{  
for $s in distinct-values(doc("class3.xml")//course/@title)
return  
<course title="{$s}">

</course>
```

}

I try to get an average from each different title.
I get the title correctly, but How I can count the average ?
I try many thing between the course tag to find the avg, can someone help me
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this within your return statement:

```
avg(doc("class3.xml")//course[@title=$s]/@note)
```

Comment: Great, exactly what it takes. In all my test I've done before, I was missing the part where [@title=s$], I understand now. Thanks Matthew

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better ways... not sure this is what you wanted but it wil help you get there I hope :)

```
let $doc := 
 <school>
 <student><name>Jack T</name>
 <course title="INF8430" note="78" />
 <course title="INF1030" note="69" />
 <course title="INF1230" note="85" /></student>
 <student><name>Marty L</name>
 <course title="INF8430" note="95" />
 <course title="INF1030" note="82" />
 <course title="INF1230" note="77" /></student>
 <student><name>Ben L</name>
 <course title="INF9430" note="59" />
 <course title="INF1030" note="78" />
 <course title="INF1230" note="79" /></student>
 </school>

return 
    for $s in $doc//student
    let $total := sum($s/course/@note) div count($s/course)
    return <name>{$s/name}<avg>{$total}</avg></name>
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Ok, you see my XML code, and the code that I use for XQuery, I want the result giving : <course title ="INF8430"> average = 86.5</course>    (Where 86.5 came from 78 + 95 / 2). So I allready get My Distinct course with this: for $s in distinct-values(doc("class3.xml")//course/@title) , but I have difficulty to reach the attribute note with the $s. Maybe a betetr way exist to get both. Thanks